# Simulating user interactions on compose UIs

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to understand how to test my Android UI written in Jetpack Compose. My assumption when switching to Compose was that I would be able to launch the app and simulate user interactions such as button clicks the same way I could with XML-based layouts using Espresso.

From what I'm reading, the Compose testing APIs rely on instantiating the composable in a test, rather than simply allowing me to run the app and simulate user interaction.

Is there any way I can do Espresso-style UI testing with my app, or is this not supported when using Compose?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about recording tests, to my knowledge this is not yet present in Jetpack Compose. However, you could still test interaction across several screens with a regular Jetpack Compose test.

See this sample Activity:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            RootComposable()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun RootComposable() {
    // This Composable will hold the NavHost 
    // and thus all other screens that will ever appear within the App
}
```

Create a test for the top-level composable, and then programmatically simulate user interactions through the whole App. You can also use an Activity reference to access String resources in your tests.

```
class RootComposableTest {

    @get:Rule
    val testRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()

    @Test
    fun rootComposable_endToEndTest() {
        val nextButtonText = testRule.activity.getString("btn_next_screen")
        val nextScreenTitle = testRule.activity.getString("title_next_screen")
        val nextNextButtonText = testRule.activity.getString("btn_next_next_screen")
        val nextNextScreenTitle = testRule.activity.getString("title_next_next_screen")

        testRule.activity.setContent {
            RootComposable()
        }

        // click button that triggers a navigation to next screen
        testRule.onNodeWithText(nextButtonText).performClick()
        // check whether next screen displays
        testRule.waitUntil(1000) { testRule.onNodeWithText(nextScreenTitle).assertExists()}
        // click button that triggers a navigation to next next screen
        testRule.onNodeWithText(nextNextButtonText).performClick()
        // check whether next next screen displays
        testRule.waitUntil(1000) { testRule.onNodeWithText(nextNextScreenTitle).assertExists()}
    }

}
```

However, Compose Testing strongly encourages to write small, modular tests, even though you could in theory test the whole app in one test. I found it useful to create separate test classes for each screen-level Composable, and then create one test for each parameter combination that Composable takes as function input.

Comment: In this case, how can I do end-to-end testing, where I simulate a user story? Such as opening the app, entering data, logging in etc. Is this kind of testing simply being discouraged?

Comment: You can do end to end tests similar to the second test I provided. With `performClick`, you can click UI buttons that trigger a navigation to the next Composable. With `performTextInput`, you can enter text into a TextField. With `waitUntil`, you can wait a predefined amount of time e.g. for a network operation to finish. So I think you should be able to achieve E2E tests as well.

Comment: What was confusing me so much was the need to set the content view on the activity, but from what I can see that's not necessary. The testing functions the same as espresso by simply setting up an `AndroidComposeRule` and calling `onNode` from there.